# update statistics in ola.hallengren maintenance solution

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

Is there a reason the default IndexOptimize job not include:

```
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
```

We will have to remember to change t incude above two lines to the job.
Is there a reason it is not included in default job?

Thanks

Comment: You can always [open an issue](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues) on the project to suggest a change.